# (Nearly) Empty source file in build

Tags: c++, bazel

I have a `proxy.h` containing an abstract class, which has a `proxy.cpp` alongside it. This header is also included elsewhere for example by implementing classes. However, `proxy.cpp` merely contains the following:

```
#include "proxy.h"
namespace myNamespace {} // where the implementation of class proxy is inside this namespace, in the header
```

Removing this file does not break the build, so I can only imagine it provides some speedup, caching or similar (using `bazel`)? Can anyone guess/explain the purpose of this source file?

Comment: It appears to me that someone (or someone's IDE) has a boilerplate header and source file creation.  As a "fill in the blank" to add the details.  And for this particular pair of files, there is no implementation.  So it's essentially empty and fallow, but benign.

Comment: Not sure that it's applicable in this particular case, but similar empty (other than a single `#include "xxx.h"` line) source files are frequently used to build pre-compiled headers.

Comment: Another **guess** would be that this file ensures that `proxy.h` is self-contained.  If this file compiles, it can be concluded that proxy.h does not require other headers to be included before it.

Comment: That still leaves the namespace as pointless line. One might expect unit test in there if you are into that sort of thing.